# Flutter Web & Firebase - Store/log information recieved from a JSON API

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I would like to log/store the data received from a JSON API to Firebase as soon as the visitor accesses my website. There are no user accounts. The API returns something akin to [this](http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) -only 1 post. I have implemented the data model using a [JSON to Dart converter](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) but I am confused about how to parse( figured how to retrieve it using HTTP) the JSON and store it in Firebase.
Here is the example model for reference.

```dart
import "dart:convert";
import "package:http/http.dart";
import "package: website/user.dar";
class Post {
  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  Post({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}
class HTTP
```

I have already successfully set up Firebase Analytics. Currently not using any other firebase packages.

### Update: Figured out how to read JSON in Dart.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'http:http.dart';
class HttpService {
  static Future<IPLocation> getLocation() async {
    Response response = await get(
        "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1");
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
      Post post = IPLocation.fromJson(body);
      return post;
    } else {
      throw Exception("Failed to load Post. StatusCode: ${response.statusCode}");
    }
  }
}
```

Now the question remains - what is the best way to store this in Firebase? I would like to map them to each visitor- but I cannot set up user accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Read Fetch and Read JSON input.

Here for clarity

```dart
import "dart:convert";
import "package:http/http.dart";
import "package: website/user.dar";
class Post {
  int userId;
  int id;
  String title;
  String body;

  Post({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.body});

  Post.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['userId'];
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userId'] = this.userId;
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['body'] = this.body;
    return data;
  }
}
```

## Firebase

Look at setting up Anonymous users using FirebaseAuth. Then set up and log userProperties.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for because I never used Firebase, but this is what I used to use to extract data from MySQL.

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Listings> listingsFromJson(String str) =>
    List<Listings>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Listings.fromJson(x)));

String listingsToJson(List<Listings> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Listings{
  Listings({
    this.customerId,
    this.image,
    this.website,
  });

  String customerId;
  String image;
  String website;

  factory Listing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Listings(
        customerId: json["customer_id"],
        image: json["image"],
        website: json["website"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "customer_id": customerId,
        "image": image,
        "website": website,
      };
}
```